# How to change text in textbox and label acording to slider value in slider in WPF, VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net

There is one huge problem in WFP, i have slider with snaped numbers 1,2. And two textboxes. Textbox1 and Textbox2.

Therefore when I start, I start with 1 on slider before moving, just how I need, and when I move slider on 2, then value "2" is showed in Textbox1 because I used binding between textbox and value of slider.
I then did this 
TexChanged Sub

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    If TextBox1.Text = "2" Then
        TextBox2.Text = "FAST"
    End If
End Sub
```

And it works, PROBLEM is when I want to move slider back, and translate value "1" on "SLOW". It blocks, what ever you do and try in any way possible. It will never allow to work with starting value of slider. You cannot do anything with value of "1".

I want this to work.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    If TextBox1.Text = "2" Then
        TextBox2.Text = "FAST"
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text = "1" Then
        TextBox2.Text = "SLOW"
    EndIf
End Sub
```

Of course when I put that under button click than everything works fine. It does not work also when I put that under slidermove also. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred way would be with a pair of triggers in Textbox2.

```
<TextBox Name="Textbox2">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TextBox1, Path=Text}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Slow"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TextBox1, Path=Text}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Fast"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Note: I just noticed that in your original example (before being edited) the second if was missing and end if. This could have been your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much will try.

Comment: Thank you, It worked perfectly well, only I just had to change frist line to    <TextBox Name="Textbox2" Margin="503,149,57,198">

Comment: OK don't forget to select an answer if you have found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned this statement "then value "2" is showed in Textbox1 because I used binding between textbox and value of slider"

Simplest way is to update the TextBox2ViewModel property on TextBox1ViewModel setter method like below,

```
Private _textBox1Value As String

Public Property TextBox1Value As String
    Get
        Return _textBox1Value
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _textBox1Value = value
        SetTextBox2Value(value)
        OnPropertyChanged("TextBox1Value")
    End Set
End Property

Private _textBox2Value As String
Public Property TextBox2Value As String

Private Sub SetTextBox2Value(ByVal value As String)
End Sub
```

Assume you have a textbox2 bound to ViewModel property, if not then you can bind it now.

Note:- The other answer (seen after my post) also makes sense, but in case if you want to have some extra logic and in case if your slider points increases to more number and if you wanted to have different text values for each slider position, then viewmodel approach is good so far I feel. Also you can unit test your viewmodel in case if you want to it.

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: In "SetTextBox2Value" method, write your logic using either switch or any other conditional statements.

Comment: Thank you will try.

Comment: I tried and there is error on OnPropertyChanged() and conflict on _textBox2Value, will try make it work your way also

Comment: Updated my answer, since my event handler has "[CallerMemberName]" so it does not require to pass parameter in my case. Sorry for the confusion.

Coming to second issue, the conflict because there might be some other property with the same name in your viewmodel. Check for the duplicate and try again.

Answer (score 0):

@Neil B has the answer but even simpler...

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=sldValue}"/>
<Slider x:Name="sldValue"/>
```